# What is the difference between "outnumber" and "outnumbered by"?

Tags: passive-voice

> 1. The women ***outnumber*** the men.
> 2. The women are ***outnumbered by*** the men.

I know the first sentence means that the count of the women is more than the count of the men. And I know that the meaning of the second sentence is the reverse: *the count of the men is more than the count of the women.* But why?

I am really confused. Why doesn't the second sentence mean: *the count of the women is increased because of the count of the men*?

Comment: Note that your #2 example is the passive of: *"The men outnumber the women."*

Comment: [Here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive) is a quick guide for passive from English Grammar Today (Cambridge Dictionaries Online). Their example about books is easier: "Cambridge University Press published this book. (active)" and "This book was published by Cambridge University Press. (passive)" - you wouldn't think that the book published the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the difference between an **[Active Voice](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/active_voice.htm)** and a **[Passive Voice](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/)**. [**Here's**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/active-and-passive-voice) the basic difference in grammar.

1. The women outnumber the men. - *This is an Active Voice*
2. The men are outnumbered by the women. - *This is a Passive Voice*

Your second sentence is just the passive for the following sentence:

- The men outnumber the women.

Comment: Thisreminds me of the [zombie test](https://beyondgrammar.wordpress.com/tag/passive/) for passive voice: the men are outnumbered [by zombies].